# how to make my own custom container - no default constructor

Tags: java

I am studying generics now and I wonder how to build a parametrized class that can store some data for me. I want to know because of c++ influence on me. Secondly, I wonder how ArrayList is built.

My problem is you cannot make new instance of a class that has no default constructor, i.e.  Integer. I know I should specialize my class in order to handle these classes individually. However, there is no specialization in Java as in c++.

How can I alter the code

```
import java.lang.*;

class test {}

class generic<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    T element;
    generic(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
    try {
        element = type.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error " + e);
    }
    }
    static <T> generic<T> create(Class<T> type) {
    return new generic<T>(type);
    }
}

public class Generic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    generic<Test> test = generic.create(Test.class);
    System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

so that it handles Integer instead of Test?

Comment: If you want to know how ArrayList works, just read the source? Also why does your container need to create new instances of the types it will create? That doesn't seem like a "container" anymore.

Comment: Class names should be `UpperCamelCase` as in `Test` and `Generic` to follow Java standard conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reaction to your class is it attempting to do two things. Create the data and store the data. As you have discovered with your experience with the Integer class, there are many classes in Java that do not expose a public constructor let alone the default constructor. So there is no single way to create object instances that can be relied on for all possible types you will encounter. You state that your requirement is to store data so let's remove the responsibility of creating data:

```
class Test {
    public String toString() {
        return "test";
    }
}

class Generic<T> {
    private T element;

    Generic(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return element.toString();
    }
}

public class GenericTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<Test> testGeneric = new Generic<Test>(new Test());
        System.out.println(testGeneric);

        Generic<Integer> integerGeneric = new Generic<Integer>(3);
        System.out.println(integerGeneric);
    }
}
```

As for wondering how `ArrayList` is built, Java is open source so you're free to inspect how all the SDK types are implemented.

Comment: I've got no idea Java is open source... Otherwise I'd never ask the question. Now I feel greatly disappointed because I believed that when someone put so much effort in generics, they use that to implement ArrayList. In reality they have only suppressed warnings...

Comment: +1 @lord.didger: Java generics allow the compiler to verify at compile-time that compiler-generated casts will not fail at run-time. Also, consider using the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it looks something like this

```
class MyArrayList<T> {
    static final int defaultSize = 10;
    Object[] array;
    int index;

    public MyArrayList() {
        array = new Object[defaultSize];
        index = 0;
    }

    public void add(T e) {
        if(index >= array.length) {
            Object[] temp = new Object[array.length*2];
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                temp[i]=array[i];
            }
            array = temp;
        }
        array[index++] = e;
    }

    public T get(int i) {
        return (T)array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution has the problem that it issues a warning that some actions are unsafe. I guess it concerns casting to T. I would like to see how it should be in Java properly written - without any notices.

Comment: BTW. it seems very strange to me that in your class I cannot use primitives as parameters, although they perfectly fit (in my c++ influenced opinion).

Comment: You can avoid the warning with `@SuppressWarnings("Unchecked")` You can't use primitives in generics.  This is because in Java, generics are syntactic sugar, whereas in C++ an new class is generated from the template.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` not having a default constructor has nothing to do with generics and everything to do with the fact that it is an immutable class.